# Vue 3 how to attach a click function to all radio buttons and in the function tell whether I clicked the already selected button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a ref object `focus = ref<number>(0)` bound to the value of a radio button group.

`<radio-button-group v-model="focus">`

and I add a watch to the ref object. Whenever the ref object's value changes (i.e. click another button), it triggers event `A`.

```js
watch(focus, () => {
        A(focus' value)// it should be noted that, at this step,
//focus' value has already changed
  })
```

However, I want to trigger event `A` even if I click the already selected button. And in this situation use focus' unchanged value as `A` parameter.

But when I clicked the already selected button, since the ref object `focus`'s value does not change, it would not trigger the `watch`.

I think if I attach a `func` to each radio button, and the func is like

```js
if(clickedSameButton)
then A(focus' value)
```

But I don't know how to implement the `if(clickedSameButton)` condition.

If I just blindly attach `func` as

```js
if(clickedButton)
then A(focus' value)
```

It won't work, since you can not tell whether focus' value is the old value or new value (if you clicked a different button) when the function `func` executes to the `then` branch, due to async execution of javascript.

For example, let's say focus' current value is 1, and current selected button is 1, when I click button 2, in the function described above

```js
if(clickedButton)
then A(focus' value)
```

You cannot know if 1 or 2 is passed to `A`

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide an example of what you did ? I think you can store the values of each radio button in `data` and check these values on your callback func, but without any more precision with what you tried, I might be completely wrong

Comment: @Zyigh I have a ref object bound to the value of the radio button group, and whenever the ref object's value changes (i.e. click another button), it triggers event `A`. However, I want to trigger event `A` even if I click the already selected button. But when I click the already selected button, since the ref object's value does not change, it would not trigger `A`. I think if I attach a `func` to each radio button, and the func is like `if(clickedSameButton)then trigger A`. But I don't know how to implement the if condition.